# CSS: label content change size of used png file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, label

How is it possible to change the size of the up and down arrow png files in the following web page snippet? They are used as a label content.

Presently they are pretty big (bigger than you think).

I would like to avoid to resize them manually with an external program, as the size has to be updated during finetuning of the web page later on several times.

```js
$("label[for]").on("click", function(event) {
  $("#input").val(function(_, n) {
    return event.target.htmlFor === "up" 
           ? +n < +this.max ? +n + 5 : n 
           : +n > +this.min ? +n - 5 : n;
  }).trigger("arrow")
});

$("#input").on("input arrow", function(event) {
  if (event.isTrigger) {
    console.log("arrow");
  } else {
    console.log("input")
  }
  console.log(this.value + "%")
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
input[type="number"] {
  width: 45px;
  outline: thin solid navy;
}
label[for="up"]:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/png/512/arrow-up-a.png);
  top: -20px !important;
  left: 32.5px;
  position: relative;
}
label[for="down"]:before {
  content: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/png/512/arrow-down-a.png);
  position: relative;
  top: 20px !important;
  left: -32.5px;
}
label[for="down"]:after {
  content: "%";
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="up"></label><input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0"><label for="down"></label>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the background image of an element and modifying the background size or making the image take up the full size of the container and altering the container's width and height. Something like this:

```js
$(".icon.up, .icon.down").on("click", function(event) {
  $("#input").val(function(_, n) {
    return event.target.classList.contains('up') 
           ? +n < +this.max ? +n + 5 : n 
           : +n > +this.min ? +n - 5 : n;
  }).trigger("arrow")
});

$("#input").on("input arrow", function(event) {
  if (event.isTrigger) {
    console.log("arrow");
  } else {
    console.log("input")
  }
  console.log(this.value + "%")
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
input[type="number"] {
  outline: thin solid navy;
  width: 100%
}

.step {
 width: 50px;
}

.icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.icon.up {
  background-image:   url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/png/512/arrow-up-a.png);
}

.icon.down {
 background-image: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/png/512/arrow-down-a.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step">
 <div class="icon up"></div>
  <input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0">
 <div class="icon down"></div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```